# Am unable to "Git Commit" my project onto my Github

Tags: git, github

I have tried several times to push my work into my github repo but after hitting **git commit -m "message"** i keep getting error message attached below:

```
$ C:\project\node_modules\.bin\commitlint --edit
⧗   input: chore: add commitlint on commit-msg
✖   Please add rules to your `commitlint.config.js`
    - Getting started guide: https://commitlint.js.org/#/?id=getting-started
    - Example config: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/blob/master/%40commitlint/config-conventional/index.js [empty-rules]

✖   found 1 problems, 0 warnings
ⓘ   Get help: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/#what-is-commitlint

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
husky - commit-msg hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Don't edit your question to answer people. Add a comment under their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the commitlint node package  from package.json or the dependent and rerun install or add a commitlint.config.js to the base of your project as the error message says and copy the example config or however you want it

the package has a hook and makes it so your commit message has to have a format but you haven’t configured it

Comment: someone has added this package so all commit have proper messages and your answer is "disable commit message check". End result will be his pull request will not be accepted and he will not learn anything useful (problem - remove functionality).

Comment: Hi marek he stated that it’s ‘my GitHub repo’ so I assumed it was his own repo therefore he added it himself unbeknownst and has not added the required config for it

Answer (score 1):

This git repository has a githook setup. In this case before a commit is committed some checks are performed if commit fulfill some requirement.

So please visit:

- https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/#what-is-commitlint
- https://commitlint.js.org/#/?id=getting-started
- https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/blob/master/%40commitlint/config-conventional/index.js

Apparently you commit message do not meet requirements. Fix commit message as [specified here](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/#what-is-commitlint).

Comment: Pls is there a way i can contact you privately? I have gone through the links you sent me and am getting confused,,I hope am not being a bother? Please